# Two live WP websites - how to sync?

Tags: server, sync

I need to have two websites in different servers, because of really slow page load times from China. So we are planning to take server from China and clone/sync website.

I'm not familiar of syncing live websites. What kind of solutions is available for this? What are the drawbacks and problems on this? What must be taken into account?

Comment: You might also look into some CDN services out there. Check out e.g. this [article on wpmudev](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/top-cdn-services-to-make-your-wordpress-site-blazingly-fast/) that discuess few options.

Comment: Actually we have used MaxCDN but still getting slow page loads from China.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically tree ways.

1. [WP API (JSON)](http://v2.wp-api.org/)
2. [Feed (XML)](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds)
3. [XMLRPC API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API)

I think the first solution via WP JSON API should be your prioritized way. The WP API will implement inside the core of WordPress in the next releases. Currently you can use it via plugin. I think, this is the standard for the next time for work with data from the WP install. Also you find a lot of tutorials, examples to use the data.
For the authentification use OAuth, like [this plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1). You find much more hints, tutorials in the [documentation about the API](http://v2.wp-api.org/). Also interest is the actually [hint from the developer side](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/12/07/rest-api-tools-and-oauth/).